# SwiftUI ScrollView w/LazyVStack calls onAppear of new elements as soon as they're added

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a scroll view with a view hierarchy as below:

```
ScrollView {
    CustomHeaderView()
    LazyVStack {
        VStack {
            ForEach(someArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        VStack {
                            someCustomView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to add pagination to this view by adding `onAppear` block. The `onAppear` blocks fire as I'd expect, EXCEPT for when users scroll very fast. It appears that once the LazyVStack adds additional subviews, the scrollview doesn't retain it's position, instead keeps scrolling to the bottom as views are added.

I'd like to be able to add subviews to the LazyVStack but have the scrollview maintain its position, so that pagination events aren't triggered endlessly as the scroll view reloads.

Comment: Two LazyVStack? Why is that?

Comment: @Asperi ah that's a mistake, have ammended.

Comment: How do you add items and how do you check for item add ?